# Limit cache size from W3 Total Cache

Tags: cache, plugin-w3-total-cache

Is it possible to define a limit for how much space W3 Total Cache is allowed to use?

Comment: No, it is not...

Comment: by _space_ I assume you mean _disk space_?

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to do this in the plugin.

It is suggested to run page cache garbage collection more frequently on high traffic sites. I expect this would keep the size of cache on disk to a reasonable amount.

Comment: Yes -- also cache fewer pages/objects, decrease object lifetime/TTL.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set quota for a directory unless it's properly mounted as a partition. Please see the following link to understand how that works

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/directory-quota-601140/#post3088656

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately this doesn't help as the current situation involved a shared host for me.